# Trouble Getting BeautifulSoup To Return Just The Movie Titles & Scores from h3 class In An href

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, web-crawler

This is the site...

https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/dvd-top-rentals/?services=amazon;amazon_prime;fandango_now;hbo_go;itunes;netflix_iw;vudu

Right clicking inspect on the titles below posters in the middle of the page brings up the code. I've tried too many variations from tutorials to post.
This is what my Python script looks like...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/dvd-top-rentals/?services=amazon;amazon_prime;fandango_now;hbo_go;itunes;netflix_iw;vudu"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
```

## NEXT STEP ????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this page is rendered by JavaScript, `requests` will only return the html code :
[image]

the real data is in this url:

```
https://www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/browse?page=1&limit=30&type=dvd-top-rentals&services=amazon%3Bamazon_prime%3Bfandango_now%3Bhbo_go%3Bitunes%3Bnetflix_iw%3Bvudu&sortBy=popularity
```

code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/browse?page=1&limit=30&type=dvd-top-rentals&services=amazon%3Bamazon_prime%3Bfandango_now%3Bhbo_go%3Bitunes%3Bnetflix_iw%3Bvudu&sortBy=popularity')

data = r.json()
for result in data["results"]:
    print(result["title"], result["tomatoScore"])
```

out:

```
The Girl on the Train 43
Keeping Up With The Joneses 19
Ouija: Origin of Evil 82
Long Way North (Tout en haut du monde) 98
The Whole Truth 29
Come And Find Me 67
LEGO Jurassic World: The Indominus Escape None
My Father, Die 88
When Elephants Were Young None
Roger Corman's Death Race 2050 None
Take the 10 None
Deepwater Horizon 83
The Accountant 51
The Birth of a Nation 72
Kevin Hart: What Now? 76
```

answer:

1. how to know if the website is rendered by JavaScript?

Just disable the JavaScript in your browser when you need to scrape a website, check if the content of page is changed.
[image]

I use this extension in chrome to disable JS with one click.

2. how to find the real url in the browser?

[image]
use chrome dev-tools's network to monitor the network activities, even the page use JS to fetch data, it still need to make a request to the server, you can find those requests in the network tab.

3. the `u''` is the represent of unicode in python2, and it's default setting in python3. it only shows in python, no need to worry about it.

Comment: Thank you so much. A few follow up questions if you don't mind.
Where did you get that link? I searched for Rotten Tomatoes API & couldn't find it. I tried to scrape data from MetaCritic.com first & it wouldn't let my Python interpreter read it. I'm new to this scraping thing. How does one find site's APIs?
How did you know it was rendered by JavaScript? Is it just something you try next after seeing what you'd normally try doesn't work?
Lastly, when I run the code I get the letter 'u' before every line. Do you know how to get rid of that?

Comment: Interesting. I still don't quite understand how you knew it was that link that was the one to use. This link (below) is a photo of my Chrome dev-tools. I inspect the movie title>> go to 'network' >> then hit reload, and I get something like your screen. The link isn't highlighted so how do you know it's the one? Is it because it's the only one that starts with 'browse'?
I tried the same thing to MetaCritic.com and there doesn't seem to be a link that starts with 'browse'.
http://imgur.com/a/4epKv

Comment: @Ant at beginning, you need check every request in the monitor, with some experience, you will notice in most case, the data will in the `XHR` tab.